# Persist data between controller methods with non-table model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, persistence

I have an app that makes graphs depending on entered text.

And I'm making it pseudo-REST as I have a form for entering text in `#new` and I want to run all calculations it `#create` and then show output on `#show` but I'm not using any storage, so data calculated in `#create` should be somehow passed to '#show' and it looks like a bad idea to put it in `session`. Is there any option to persist data just for redirection to other   method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In you `def create` function instead of redirecting to show why not just do this:

```
render "show"
```

Comment: I've though of it, but in a REST way you should see the resource on `/show` and not `/create`

Comment: The the only other option is to store the data in the session or in a file on disk.

Answer (score 0):

Eric Sites gave a very good answer, but I want to show the other point of view concerning REST idea.

As I've said in the question: I'm not saving and data e.i. creating resources. So I suggest to send the data from form directly to `#show` and preferably by `GET`.

This way `#new` action will give you form for a new resource and `#show` action will show you resource specified by URI and constructed *on the fly*